# Is it "correct" to do a binary mathematical operation by converting to decimal?

Tags: math

Is it considered correct in order to do a binary or hexadecimal operation to convert to decimal, do the operation, and then convert back to the original numeral system?

Is the above not advised?
Is the above frawned upon?

The context is a (first year) Programming Open University Course and the guide (in lack of a better word to describe him) is delaying my enquiry.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly. Converting to decimal to do binary ops sounds like a really strange idea. Could you illustrate your question with an example (pseudo-code)?

Comment: yes for example an exercise could to add the following two hex numbers: 1AD9 + 201D. We've been taught of a way to do it, but its hard. It seems easier to me to convert to decimal, add them, and then convert the result to hexadecimal

Comment: The complexity of addition is the same, the algorithm is the same in all bases. If you did it programmatically, there would be no difference with the way you do it for base 10 or 16 (or any other base really).

Comment: The exercise would be in written form - not programmatically.

Comment: Ah, then the conversion(s) won't change the result unless you mess it up.

Comment: Even if the result is the same - is it bad practise? Should I just practise adding hexadecimal or binary numbers (or any operation for that matter)? Is it important? Or being able to convert them to decimal is enough and I should go on with the reading?

Comment: You'll waste a lot of time on the conversions, and you increase the chance of error since you'll be doing more calculations. Whether that's good/bad and what you should do is entirely up to you. We don't know your teacher so we can't know what he/she expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's generally correct. Numbers are numbers, no matter how you represent them as text. Note that binary, decimal, and hexadecimal are all *text* representations of numbers.